# Display MS access data in Jtable netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am trying to display my db in a jtable on netbeans but my form just opens up blank.

heres the code i used, also does not findConnectDB

```
public class BuyingScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;



FlyKitemain fk = new FlyKitemain();

private void UpdateJTable(){
    String sql = "Select * From tblKites";

    try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        BuyingTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}

      catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(BuyingScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}


private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){

    conn = FlyKitemain.ConnectDB();
    UpdateJTable();
}
```

[image: my form design]

Comment: Post a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `" also does not findConnectDB"` -- fix your problems one at a time. This is your main problem and should be solved in isolation and not in a complex GUI program. So first figure out how to successful connect to your database source, get data from it, and only then try to integrate it with a GUI. If still stuck, show this small database program, especially where you try to connect with the database (you for some reason have not shown this critical code here(??)), and show all exception or error messages with your question.